# How to make zoomable LinearLayout?

Tags: android, zooming

I am having an xml file which I want to make zoomable.

Comment: Change font size......

Comment: http://myandroidnote.blogspot.ch/2011/03/zooming-view-completely.html see this link

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[use this jar in your application](http://code.google.com/p/android-zoom-view/downloads/list)

1.Create a new layout (R.layout.zoomableview) for Views that i want to apply the zooming functionality.

2.Place it inside ZoomView.

3.Then place the ZoomView to the main container where you want to show the zoomable view.

```
private ZoomView zoomView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoomable);

View v = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.zoomableview, null, false);
v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

zoomView = new ZoomView(this);
zoomView.addView(v);

main_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_container);
main_container.addView(zoomView);            }
```

Comment: @BlackTiger which layout we can declare in inflate layout .......

Comment: @N.V.R which layout we can declare in inflate layout .......

Comment: Great! its working :)

Comment: Awesome! +1 and job done :)

Comment: what is R.layout.zoomableview??

Comment: @JibranKhan How to I set the dynamic image from gallery in the zoomView? Can you help me please?

Comment: @reegan29 add imageview in zoomview and change the source of image dynamically from gallery

Comment: @venkat
Its working ...
but its not working smoothly..

Comment: why not you answer the questions in comments ?

Comment: great at last its working. R.layout.activity_zoomable has the only one root layout named main_container, and your real xml file should be another the zoomable layout which inflated.

Comment: for complete implementation refer to :                                
https://github.com/mosayeb-masoumi/zoom_whole_recyclerview