# How to implement zoom effect and draw Grid for Table Layout in android?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, zooming

i have to implement image zooming in Table layout and image zooming also, I have try so many codes.But i didn't get full idea of gesture events. I want to implement when image zooming than grid zoom. Image zoom with gesture event. I have so many code implement but only image is zoom not grid .Can any body suggest me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508850/zoom-a-view-over-layout-in-android/18508998#18508998

Comment: make your grid in html and try the above link

Answer (score 2):

set image in image-view and apply zooming effect on it. Create View on image-view draw grid on the View. After set zooming effect on both image-view and View.

Comment: i try out this. but only image is zooming not view(grid).