# How to make screen re-sizable?

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I'm working on my Android project and I'm trying to get my screen re sizable. So when I run my app on device I want to be able with touching the screen zoom in or zoom out. Can someone help with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have look into http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849060/how-to-make-zoomable-linearlayout