# How to write subscript under superscript in xml?

Tags: android, xml, subscript, superscript

I am working with android textview. I need print subscript under superscript.

This is my code:

```
<string name="abc">Text<sup>supertext</sup><sub>subtext</sub></string>
```

And this is what i get:

Text<sup>suertext</sup><sub>subtext</sub>

But i need something like:

[image]

Is it possible to do that only in XML without using java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create vertically aligned superscript and subscript in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990381/how-to-create-vertically-aligned-superscript-and-subscript-in-textview)

Comment: I forgot to ask if it is possible to do that without java... I am sorry...

Comment: Not really. It's just HTML; in order to do this with plain old HTML you'd have to mess with CSS to do it, and even then, ew. I think you'd be better off creating a custom control of some sort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use 2 text views. One with "Text" and next to it a multi line text view with "Supertext...".

However only do that if it's not strings that may ever be translated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, there is a problem, because when i want to zoom it, i can zoom only one textview :(

Comment: But it is good point, I will mark it as correct answer,... mby somebody is looking for this :)

Comment: I haven't done this myself but couldn't you wrap them in a linear layout and pinch zoom the linear layout?

Comment: [Pinch Zoom Linear Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367291/pinch-zoom-for-linearlayout-in-android)