# android make my LinearLayout zoomable

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a LinearLayout, wrapped in a `ScrollView`, that contains mostly `TextViews` and sometimes `ImageViews`. Now i want to give the user the possibility to zoom in(and out again) with two fingers. Is there an easy way to do that? Here is the extract from the xml-file:

```
<ScrollView
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/15850113/5515371

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make zoomable LinearLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849060/how-to-make-zoomable-linearlayout)

Comment: hmm i'm very cautious with libraries, since the app will be sold in google play store and i don't understand much of licenses. What would i have to do if i use that? i read the license.txt, but didn't understand much of it

Answer (score 1):

Use
[ZoomView](https://github.com/Polidea/android-zoom-view/blob/master/src/pl/polidea/view/ZoomView.java)

It will provide functionality to zoom layout by pinch.

```
ZoomView zoomView = new ZoomView(this);
zoomView.addView(layout);
```

Comment: hmm i'm very cautious with libraries, since the app will be sold in google play store and i don't understand much of licenses. What would i have to do if i use that? i read the license.txt, but didn't understand much of it

Comment: It is free to use, I've also used it in one of my live apps

Comment: ok, but i don't get it to work nicely with `ScrollView`  together. If i put the `Zoomview` inside the `ScrollView`, it doesn't zoom to right position, but somewhere below. If i put the `ScrollView` inside the `ZoomView` it zooms correct but scrolling doesn't work right

Comment: Yeah I remember that I haven't used it with any view with scroll behavior.